# Ethernet Link is going down while applying EFT pulses on Power Port

Tags: noise, transient-suppression

We have conducted our system for EFT test as per IEC-61000-4-4. We have applied EFT on the AC side of the AC-DC power supply. We are using the power supply [HWS50A-12/A](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/power/switching-power/ac-dc-converter/info?part_no=HWS50A-12%2FA) from TDK-Lambda. As per the manufacturer claim, the power supply has the protection against EFT and it is compliant. Also, we have given protection circuits on our board on DC power entry. While applying the pulses on the AC side, we are noticing that the ethernet link is going down and it automatically comes up. I have connected the Ethernet cable from my board to a laptop and it was continuously pinging. While applying pulses the link is going down and that time only it will come back and it will continue the ping test automatically. Can any help me to solve this issue? 
I have attached the [image: test setup and observation] and the i[image: nput filter circuit]. 
Best Regards,
Shafeeq

Comment: EFT is rare in the wild, your system recovers after a few seconds, why is this a problem?

Comment: The requirement is Performance criteria A. With this issue the performance criteria will be B.

Comment: I assume you've checked that the power to your cpu/ethernet MAC etc. are fine during the EFT event. What steps have you taken to avoid coupling the EFT pulses into the ethernet cable via the centre taps of the magjack transformers?

Comment: @james Can you suggest any option for this?

Comment: For checking the power a good high bandwidth differential scope probe (or simply having your cpu log any anomalies). For avoiding the coupling - the first thing I'd do is look at how your DC ground and Frame ground/PE are connected. Presumably that's in the PSU?

Comment: @james what you meant by frame ground?
Whether it is frame ground?

Comment: You have a protective earth coming into the box PE. Your power supply has a metal frame (Frame ground)  which you may or may not have connected to PE. It may or may not connect that metal frame to the DC output Ground, and you may or may not have have connected it somwhere, and finally you have the DC ground you're using after your power input filter. How are they all connected together (including capacitors and movs that you have added), and have you created any loops at either DC or AC.

Comment: @james The FG and PE have been shorted in PSU. Additionally, in my board, I have given 1000pf capacitor, 1M resistor and a bidirectional TVS diode between DC ground and the PE.

Comment: and how physically are they connected, how is the EFT pulse dissipated by your MOVs, and where does that current flow, remember your 1nF caps will look like shorts to the pulse. Does any of it flow through you DC chokes, and does it cause ground bounce for the mag-jack shield?

Comment: @james in PSU, FG and PE are connected through a mounting screw. In our board also PE is connected to a mounting hole. From there with thick traces, we have connected the 1nF cap, 1M res and TVS to DC ground. And I didn't probe any of the lines while testing. MOVs will not be much effective for the pulses as the response time of MOVs are more. That we have considered for surge application. Anyhow as you can understand from the schematics, for MOV3 and D15, current flow will be from DC+ to DC-. For the other two pairs, the flow will be to the PE.

Comment: @james could you please tell which choke you are referring and how it causes for the ground bounce for Magjack shield?

Comment: Your circuit shunts faults to ground, does your layout cause, for example current to flow from J11 pin 1, though FB14, E7 and C135? When this happens does your layout have some of that current flowing past the connection to the magjack? Or are the connexions to protective earth made in such a way to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Once EFT is applied on the Earth connection, it can get in to your system ground and spoil the Ethernet. One way to avoid it is have a common mode choke at AC inuput (line, neutral, ground) after your coupling device (at the entry of your equipment.)